# CentOS 6.4 iSCSI Target - crm shell error

Tags: centos, iscsi, pacemaker, crm

I try to make a iSCSI Target on CentOS 6.4 with DRBD, Pacemaker, Open-iSCSI and LVM2.

Now I need to prepare the HA iSCSI Target configuration on the crm shell, but if I enter the configure mode, there's a error message:

```
[root@centos ~]# crm
crm(live)# configure
ERROR: running cibadmin -Q1: Could not establish cib_rw connection: Connection refused (111)
Signon to CIB failed: Transport endpoint is not connected
Init failed, could not perform requested operations
```

Because crm is not included in the newest pacemaker-cli package, I added [this](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/network:/ha-clustering:/Stable/CentOS_CentOS-6/network:ha-clustering:Stable.repo) OpenSUSE Repo, before I installed the package `crmsh.x86_64`.

**cat /var/log/messages | grep corosync:**

```
corosync[1052]:   [MAIN  ] Compatibility mode set to whitetank. Using V1 and V2 of the synchronization engine.
corosync[1052]:   [TOTEM ] A processor joined or left the membership and a new membership was formed.
corosync[1052]:   [CPG   ] chosen downlist: sender r(0) ip(127.0.0.1) ; members(old:0 left:0)
pacemakerd[1259]:   error: find_corosync_variant: Corosync is running, but Pacemaker could not find the CMAN or Pacemaker plugin loaded 
corosync[1052]:   [TOTEM ] The network interface [192.168.1.101] is now up.
corosync[1052]:   [TOTEM ] A processor joined or left the membership and a new membership was formed.
corosync[1052]:   [CPG   ] chosen downlist: sender r(0) ip(127.0.0.1) ; members(old:0 left:0)
corosync[1052]:   [MAIN  ] Completed service synchronization, ready to provide service.
```

**cat /var/log/messages | grep pacemaker:**

```
pacemakerd[1251]:   error: find_corosync_variant: Corosync is running, but Pacemaker could not find the CMAN or Pacemaker plugin loaded
pacemakerd[1251]:   notice: get_cluster_type: This installation does not support the ´(null)´ cluster infrastructure: terminating.
```

Comment: In RHEL5 you needed to run the cman service too: "service cman start". Don't know about RHEL6.

Comment: can you show your cluster configuration? have you tried this guide http://clusterlabs.org/quickstart-redhat.html ?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use anything from the Suse repo except **crmsh** and **pssh** so you should add a line to the repo file which says `includepkgs=crmsh,pssh` so that it does not overwrite the CentOS supplied corosync etc.

The only supported method of using corosync on **CentOS 6.4** is to use it via **cman** so you no longer start corosync directly, you start cman and then you start pacemaker. Configuration is done via `/etc/cluster/cluster.conf` and this tells **cman** how to start corosync.

You should see these pages for more details: [Pacemaker on RHEL6.4](http://blog.clusterlabs.org/blog/2013/pacemaker-on-rhel6-dot-4/) and [Pacemaker and RHEL 6.4 (Redux)](http://blog.clusterlabs.org/blog/2013/pacemaker-and-rhel-6-dot-4/)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe that because your cluster doesn't work, you should use crm_mon to confirm it. Only in you cluster worked, crm configure can use.